# Excel - return cell value from each row if text is found in cell range in same row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I have 3 columns with names in it and the rows are simply named Row1-Row9.

I want to list all rows where a name is found to be any part of a cell (not exact match).

So, I'm searching for the name and if found in a row, return the A cell value from that row.

I've made a sample in the image provided. I've looked at a lot of different "if" formulas for excel but could not find an answer for this.

I can manually put each name into the formula for each unique person, but just cannot figure out how to return the A1 cell values per row when looking for a name.[image]

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Mac 365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A14,B2:D8)),A2:A8,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Yours is a lot cleaner. Didn't know the ranges within SEARCH in combination with IF could differ like that and still return the correct row.

Comment: I'm not getting "function invalid" with this version, but oddly I'm not returning anything either. Maybe Mac365 is the issue? using this which is the correct ranges: 
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B145,BP3:BS142)),C3:C142,""))

Comment: getting an invalid function error in Windows 365 version, but my version looks the same as yours which seems to be working. All fields are set to General type - can't think of what I could be doing wrong (?). I even tried creating a new blank file with your simple example and got an error. When I close the error, Windows highlights this part of the formula: ",TRUE,IF

Comment: Can you share a sample file via google drive or dropbox so that can check.

Comment: how about this: https://ibb.co/t4YQQ7v

Comment: Can you try to replace comma with semicolon. Due to regional and language settings it may issue with comma. Otherwise your formula looks just fine.

Comment: oh, yes - which comma though?

Comment: Replace all commas except first one.

Comment: yes, thank you - this does work now - thanks!!!!

Comment: Then please mark the answer as accepted. Tick mark it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241364/discussion-between-user2554201-and-harun24hr).

Answer (score 0):

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A2:A10,SIGN(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A14,C2:E10)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C2:E10),,,0))),"No matches"))`

This requires Office 365.

Where `A14` is the search value, `C2:E10` is the search range and `A2:A10` is the return range.

Comment: Thanks, my formula looks like this using 365 on Mac, getting an error. Do you see an issue? 
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(C3:C142,SIGN(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B145,BP3:BS142)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(BP3:BS142),,,0)))))

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNxmY.jpg maybe add an error handling for the filter if nothing's found: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(C3:C142,SIGN(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B145,BP3:BS142)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(BP3:BS142),,,0))),"No matches"))`